# Using Native Query Multiple Queries Single Resultset

Tags: jpa, nativequery

Using JPA, I am trying to fetch data from different tables and to have it in single result list using query:

```
SELECT x.a, y.b FROM (SELECT * from a) as x, (SELECT * FROM b) as y
```

However it is throwing an exception:

```
Caused by: com.sap.sql.sqlparser.CommonSQLParserException: - 1:256 - SQL syntax error: not a table reference
- 1:256 - Intermediate-SQL syntax error: table reference must be a table name
- 1:261 - SQL syntax error: arguments in FROM clause of SELECT must be tables or a JOIN of tables
- 1:423 - SQL syntax error: not a table reference
- 1:423 - Intermediate-SQL syntax error: table reference must be a table name
- 1:527 - SQL syntax error: not a table reference
```

Please adivse on how to resolve or reconstruct the above query.

Comment: Does this work in SQL?  If the SQL isn't valid, it won't work in JPA either.  Why doesn't just "Select x.a, y.b FROM a x, b y" work for you?  What values are you trying to get?

Comment: Couple of distinct values from a table seperately,

here is the complete details:

String strQuery = SELECT x.a, y.b FROM (select distinct l.xx as a , h.yy from Table1 l INNER JOIN Table2 h ON l.yy = h.yy where h.zz > ?) as a, select distinct l.xx as b , h.yy from Table1 l INNER JOIN Table2 h ON l.yy = h.yy where h.zz > ?) as b) as y;

query = em.createNativeQuery(strQuery, ClassName.class);

query.setParameter(1, value); 

List<RetWrapper> LResult = query.getResultList();